# Extract a line of C code using perl based on filename + line number

Tags: c, perl

I'm looking to extract a statement of C code given the filename and linenumber where it begins.

I can't, of course, just take the line, as I could have something like:

```
foo(i,
   j, "this is ); \
   ", k);
```

as the example indicates, I also can't look for the next `);` either, which would make it fairly simple.

Is there anything out there, presumably on CPAN, which does this automatically?

If I could run the code through indent first, I would have it allow unlimited line lengths, and then take just that line, but if I do that, I lose the line number!

Comment: Your example is not valid C, as you cannot have an embedded newline inside a string. There can be a newline used for line continuation, though, but that is recognizable by the backslash `\` that precedes it.

Comment: What did you have in mind as 'a complete statement' when the line contains '`for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {`?  Do you need to find the matching closing brace?  What about when it does not contain the open brace; do you still want the loop body?

Comment: @jk you are correct; I edited the question.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: well, the C spec defines exactly what the statement is there... but in all honesty, it doesn't matter. I know that the line will only contain one of about a dozen statements, all function calls (technically, it could have two statements on one line, but I'm assuming that will never happen).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this perfectly well, you'd need a full-blown C parser in Perl. However, you can cover probably more than 99% of all cases with a much simpler algorithm:

1. Open the file
2. Skip lines until you reach the line in question
3. Slurp lines until you reach a semicolon at the end of the line

"Semicolon at end of line" is a pretty decent heuristic for "end of statement". Relatively simple quote-parsing might protect you from the situation shown above.

If you need something more sophisticated than that, you might look at [C::Scan](http://search.cpan.org/~hvds/C-Scan-0.74/Scan.pm) and its subclasses, or [Inline::C::ParseRecDescent](http://search.cpan.org/~sisyphus/Inline-0.46/C/lib/Inline/C/ParseRecDescent.pm).